# How can bare repositories be copied, preserving sharedrepository and its effect?

Tags: git, permissions

I need to be able to copy a repository set up like this:

```
$ git init --bare --shared=0666 first.git
```

yielding this config:

```
$ git --git-dir=first.git config core.sharedrepository
0666
```

to a second repository with the same configuration.

---

On disk it looks like this:

```
[drwxrwsrwx] first.git/
```

but when cloning this repository:

```
git clone --bare first.git second.git
```

the second repository has permissions:

```
[drwxrwxrwx] first.git/
```

Note: `s` -> `x`, and also:

```
$ git --git-dir=second.git config core.sharedrepository
[exit code: 1]
```

---

Is there a way to do this with `git-clone`? I've looked at `--mirror` and other options but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. It requires the use of `git-init` to "reinitialize" the repository:

```
git clone --bare first.git second.git
git init --bare --shared=0666 second.git
```

Since it was cloned by one user, this user then has permissions to perform an after-the-fact fix to the repository, essentially chmod'ing the necessary parts. Would be nice if this was incorporated into clone though.